# Getting different results while comparing reports from SonarQube UI and JSON report generated

Tags: sonarqube

While generating JSON report for a project from SonarQube 6.4, I am getting different results in the report as compared to what I see in the UI for the same project.

I am using the following web api method to generate the report: `http://localhost:9000/api/measures/component?&metricKeys=ncloc,coverage,critical_violations,violations,blocker_violations,major_violations,minor_violations,info_violations,functions,function_complexity_distribution&componentKey=`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some detail on how you're generating this JSON report.

Comment: i am using the web api methods http://localhost:9000/api/measures/component?&metricKeys=ncloc,coverage,critical_violations,violations,blocker_violations,major_violations,minor_violations,info_violations,functions,function_complexity_distribution&componentKey=
to generate the report. I am getting different number of violations as compared to UI.

Comment: And what filters are applied in the UI? If you remove them all, do the numbers match?

Comment: I didn't apply any filters in the UI but some of the violations are in the category of false positive. Is that creating an issue?

Comment: Double check whether filters are being auto-applied for you

Comment: I checked for filters and clicked on "clear All filters". After that ran an analysis and again there is a difference of 5 critical bugs. Adding to the previous comment I also have certain issues under fixed category, is that creating any problem?